# i cant import numpy in pycharm and its showing errors even after running pip install numpy in cmd

Tags: numpy, pycharm

even after trying pip install numpy in cmd i cannot get the numpy module installed in pycharm.
      i have also tried to add numpy using project interpreter.
           numpy is being listed in the available modules but it cannot be installed.
The screenshot of the error is placed below. please help me out

[image]

Comment: not very familiar with windows, from the error it seems like you need to install Visual C++ , try see https://support.microsoft.com/en-sg/help/2977003/the-latest-supported-visual-c-downloads

Comment: problem solved after installing build tools